# WordPress Permalinks only work with index.php in the URL

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

When I try to change my WordPress Permalink settings, links to posts and pages return a 404 page. I have found the only way to get them to work is to either use Plain permalinks or to include /index.php/ in my permalink url, like **domain.com/index.php/postname**. How can I get them to work without index.php being part of the URL?

My .htaccess is below, and I have also used the .htaccess suggested at https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#creating-and-editing-htaccess, but changes to the permalinks puts the code below back into the htaccess file. Mod_rewrite is enabled on my Apache server.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change permalink settings in wp-admin to 'PLAIN' permalinks
2. Install mod_rewrite module in apache (ensure using php_info that its enabled)
3. The most important part, in
   /etc/apache/apache2.conf (NOTE THAT YOU MUST CHANGE THE NAME OF
   FOLDER):

> ```
> <Directory />
>     Options FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride All
>     Require all denied
>  </Directory>
>
>  <Directory /usr/share>
>     AllowOverride None
>     Require all granted
>  </Directory>
>
>  <Directory /var/www/>
>     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride All
>     Require all granted
>  </Directory>
>
>  #<Directory /srv/>
>  #  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>  #  AllowOverride None
>  #  Require all granted
>  #</Directory>
>
>  <Directory "/var/www/html/NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER"> --> Edit this part
>  Options FollowSymLinks
>  AllowOverride All  -->make sure its ALL
>  </Directory>
> ```

4. Re-enabled post based or any other permalink